# get desired element in numpy array of unequal row lengths, without using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

i have the below numpy array:

```
array([['apple','banana','orange'],
   ['car','bike','train','ship','plane','scooter'],
   ['red','purple']], dtype=object)
```

the individual rows in the array are of unequal length, I want to get the last element of each row. I can get this by running a for loop but I guess there could be more direct way to doing so. The closest (wrong solution) i have is arr[:][-1] which gives me element of last row and arr[np.arange(len(arr)),-1] which throws an 'IndexError' error.

My desired output is:

```
array([['orange','scooter','purple']], dtype=object)
```

I will appreciate any guidance. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Pandas:

```
In [87]: a
Out[87]: array([['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], ['car', 'bike', 'train', 'ship', 'plane', 'scooter'], ['red', 'purple']], dtype=object)

In [88]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [93]: df
Out[93]:
                                          0
0                   [apple, banana, orange]
1  [car, bike, train, ship, plane, scooter]
2                             [red, purple]

In [94]: df[0].str[-1]
Out[94]:
0     orange
1    scooter
2     purple
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

or as a NumPy array:

```
In [95]: df[0].str[-1].values
Out[95]: array(['orange', 'scooter', 'purple'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: this solution works. my original data was pandas DF and I played around with .str operations but this solution didn't strike me. thank you. This is how i did it with pandas itself:
arr['0'] = arr['0'].str.split().str[-1]

Comment: `pandas` never fails it seems! ;)

Comment: @Divakar, only in those cases when it's slower compared to NumPy... ;)

Comment: @SirajS., here is an alternative solution: `arr['0'].str.extract(r'\s*([^\s]+)$', expand=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of list if the fastest:

```
import numpy as np
import random

items = ['apple','banana','orange', 'car','bike','train','ship','plane','scooter', 'red','purple']
a = [random.sample(items, random.randint(2, 10)) for _ in range(1000)]
b = np.array(a)

%timeit [x[-1] for x in a] # 62.1 µs
%timeit [x[-1] for x in b] # 75.9 µs
f = np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[-1], 1, 1)
%timeit f(b)  # 165 µs

import cytoolz
%timeit list(cytoolz.pluck(-1, a)) # 42.7 µs
%timeit list(cytoolz.pluck(-1, b)) # 75.8 µs

import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(a)
%timeit s.str[-1] # 965 µs
```

Even you have a DataFrame or Series object, you can convert it to a list first:

```
%timeit s.tolist() #45.6 µs
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loop comprehension : `np.array([i[-1] for i in arr],dtype=object)` might just be an efficient and fast way, specially if the lists are long enough. But since you are asking for a non-loopy solution, here's a way using [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to get a flattened version and then indexing into it with proper indices for the selection of final elements of each list -

```
np.concatenate(arr)[np.cumsum(map(len,arr))-1]
```

There's an use of `map` operator, which doesn't look like a vectorized operation, but since we are using it to only get the lengths of the lists, that part should not be heavy on runtime. So, I guess it's an almost vectorized approach.

Sample run -

```
In [166]: arr
Out[166]: 
array([['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
       ['car', 'bike', 'train', 'ship', 'plane', 'scooter'],
       ['red', 'purple']], dtype=object)

In [167]: np.concatenate(arr)[np.cumsum(map(len,arr))-1]
Out[167]: 
array(['orange', 'scooter', 'purple'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Please note that if we want an object dtype array, we would need to convert to such dtype before indexing : `np.concatenate(arr).astype(object)`.